# Does Batman ever say "Because I'm Batman" in-universe?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-extended-universe

"How It Should Have Ended" has a shtick about "[Because I'm Batman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpIQQeL2ZYk)" that turned into a meme by now.

But did HISHE invent it, or does Batman **actually say that exact phrase** in any canon, comic or film?

I'd prefer the phrase to be stated in correct context (as an explanation/reason for something).

Comment: [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74055/when-did-batman-say-i-am-batman-for-the-first-time) doesn't count as it's not the exact phrase.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaM_tYWBdyU

Comment: From the LEGO Batman trailer, which I don't think really counts as it's not part of the actual movie, and came after HISHE. https://youtu.be/aBJyp2LFHgk?t=22s

Answer (score 6):

I believe using the phrase `*because* I'm Batman` is original to HISHE. There are plenty of instances where Batman has said `I'm Batman` both in comics and movies. And there was Frank Miller's `I'm the goddamned Batman.`

[Tv Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Quotes/Batman) (*Danger Will Robinson!*) has lots of instances of him saying `I'm Batman` across variable medium, but it is only in HISHE that he uses the exact phrasing *because.*

In the HISHE Superman episode, Batman says "cause I'm Batman." This is the introduction of the Super Cafe with Superman and Batman.

> Superman: I know. You say that a lot.
>   Batman: I carry things on my belt. Cause I’m Batman.
>   Superman: Dude, it's cool.

The first time in HISHE that Batman says "**Because** I'm Batman" is in his next appearance, in the Spider-Man 3 episode.

> Batman: ... Because I'm Batman.
>   Superman: Dude, it's cool.

Comment: Again, lacking the because, but it's implied, http://www.shortpacked.com/2005/comic/book-1-brings-back-the-80s/01-just-a-toy-store/batman-can-breathe-in-space/ predates HISHE for using "I'm Batman" as an all purpose explanation.

Comment: @starpilotsix Add it as an answer. Although, that fan comic fails to explain how Superman can talk into a microphone while in space without a helmet. I hope it isn't because he's Superman.

Comment: @JackBNimble he could just hold his breath and then when he needs to speak he has air in his lungs that he can push out so that there is a medium for the sounds to travel through... It's possible, they just probably weren't thinking that.